# 'NSError' is not convertible to 'AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>'

Tags: error-handling, swift, avaudioplayer

In my iOS application I need to play sound. I have the following code:

```
var audioFileLocationUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("midnight", ofType: "m4a")
var error: NSError
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileLocationUrl, error: error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

On line:

```
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileLocationUrl, error: error)
```

I have error: Could not find overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit (it was pointed out to me that there is a clear difference between when to use NSErrorPointer and when to use NSError?. Here is the official word:

From “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.”

“When you need to report the reason for the error, you can add to the function an NSError out parameter of type NSErrorPointer. This type is roughly equivalent to Objective-C’s NSError **, with additional memory safety and optional typing. You can use the prefix & operator to pass in a reference to an optional NSError type as an NSErrorPointer object, as shown in the code listing below.

```
var writeError : NSError? 
AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileLocationUrl, error: &writeError)
```

Comment: This is wrong; the `NSError` is what you want to hold onto, so your local variable should be `NSError?`. The prefix `&` operator will do the pointer part for you. Furthermore, you're declaring an optional value as `nil` and immediately unwrapping it, which is an error. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_9)

Comment: You are right! I learned something today. I've changed my answer to be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var error :NSError?

audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileLocationUrl, error: &error)
```

Failing that check you're calling the right method and passing in the right object types.

The reason you get this warning is because the compiler can't find that init method with those parameters.

Comment: is audioFileLocationUrl a URL or a string, suspect it's a string maybe?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Error handling has changed drastically in Swift 2. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_9) for the latest info.

---

For me, this code produces the error **'NSError' is not convertible to 'AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>'**. This is because the method is trying to take an error *by reference* so it can "write back" to your local variable. [In Obj-C](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-ownership-restrictions-pass-by-writeback) this looks like `(NSError **)`. (Fun fact: `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>` is aliased to `NSErrorPointer` in Swift.)

In fact, if you ⌘-click on AVAudioPlayer to see its declaration, you'll find the init method is defined as

```
init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL!, error outError: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>)
```

For this reason, you must:

1. use an `NSError?` (i.e. `Optional<NSError>`) variable, since the error may be `nil`.
2. Pass the error in by reference with the prefix `&` operator.

   ```
   var error: NSError?
   ...
   audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileLocationUrl, error: &error)
   ```

See [Error Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_9) in "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" for more information.

Comment: What do you mean? `error` may be nil (because it's `NSError?`) but it needs to be `NSError&` so that you can pass `error: &error`.

Comment: i mean audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileLocationUrl, error: nil)